# Data Missing while parsing xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have xml data in a table like given below.

```
<App action="A" id="1">
<BaseVehicle id="822" />
<!-- 1986 Volvo 740 -->
<EngineBase id="2137" />
<!-- L6 2.4L -->
<Qty>6</Qty>
<PartType id="7152" />
<!-- Diesel Glow Plug -->
<MfrLabel>Diesel Glow Plug</MfrLabel>
<Part>0250201032</Part>
```

When I parsed the data with below code, I am missing  `1986 Volvo 740` 
and `L6 2.4L`

I am trying to pull this data in a column called BaseVehicle and PartType respectively. Under datatype VARCHAR.

May any Please help me what is the error in below code

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY one.App.value('@id', 'int') ) AS AppID ,
    1 AS FileID ,
    one.App.value('@action', 'varchar(10)') AS Action ,
    one.App.value('@id', 'int') AS ID ,
    one.App.value('BaseVehicle[1]/@id', 'int') AS BaseVehicleID ,
    **one.App.value('BaseVehicle[1]', 'VARCHAR (100)') AS BaseVehicle ,**
    one.App.value('BodyType[1]/@id', 'int') AS BodyTypeID ,
    one.App.value('BodyType[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS BodyType ,
    one.App.value('Qty[1]', 'int') AS Qty ,
    one.App.value('PartType[1]/@id', 'int') AS PartTypeID ,
    **one.App.value('PartType[1]', 'VARCHAR (100)') AS PartType ,**
    one.App.value(' SubModelID[1]/@id', 'int') AS SubModelID ,
    '<Quals>' + CAST(one.App.query('Qual') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '</Quals>' AS QualNodes ,
    '<Notes>' + CAST(one.App.query('Note') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '</Notes>' AS NoteNodes ,
    one.App.query('.') AS AppNode

FROM    NETCHANGESource.dbo.tblFile s
        CROSS APPLY s.xmldata.nodes('/ACES/App') AS one ( app );
```

Comment: Show XML in column, not just part of it.

Comment: @lad2025:  **one.App.value('BaseVehicle[1]', 'VARCHAR (100)') AS BaseVehicle ,** and  **one.App.value('PartType[1]', 'VARCHAR (100)') AS PartType ,**

Comment: `<!-- 1986 Volvo 740 -->` is comment, not actual data

Comment: Missing values are <!-- 1986 Volvo 740 --> and <!-- Diesel Glow Plug -->

Comment: @lad2025: is there any way to get it.

Comment: @lad2025: something like comment under specific id (BaseVehicleID OR PartTypeID)

Comment: @lad2025: i am sorry if my question looks non sense, pretty new to xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prepare your XML correctly and do not rely on data in comments.

To read data in comments you could use `comments()` XQuery:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<ACES>
    <App action="A" id="1">
      <BaseVehicle id="822" />
      <!-- 1986 Volvo 740 -->
      <EngineBase id="2137" />
      <!-- L6 2.4L -->
      <Qty>6</Qty>
      <PartType id="7152" />
      <!-- Diesel Glow Plug -->
      <MfrLabel>Diesel Glow Plug</MfrLabel>
      <Part>0250201032</Part>
   </App>
 </ACES>';

SELECT  
   one.App.value('comment()[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') AS comment_1,
   one.App.value('comment()[2]', 'nvarchar(1000)') AS comment_2,
   one.App.value('comment()[3]', 'nvarchar(1000)') AS comment_3
FROM ...
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/417528)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════════╗
║   comment_1    ║ comment_2 ║     comment_3     ║
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 1986 Volvo 740 ║ L6 2.4L   ║ Diesel Glow Plug  ║
╚════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Comment: getting error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: @akhrot This is example how to retrieve data not code you copy and paste. You need to adjust it for your needs. Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com with all needed structure and sample data.